# How to disable or edit Google Chrome Developer Tools shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

There is a shortcut in the Google Chrome Developer Tools which happen to trigger every times I try to type the <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> character in the console. The shortcut in question probably is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> or <kbd>[</kbd> and it moves the tabs (of the Chrome Developer Tools) to the last selected one. This shortcut is simply blocking me from typing the <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> in the console and I want to either disable it or edit it to something else. How can I edit or disable that shortcut ?

Note : I'm not really using the shortcut in the developers tools, so if it's only possible to disable all shortcut it would be a viable solution.

Comment: I have raised a new Chromium issue at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168164 . Personally, I do not expect keyboard shortcut customization to be available in Chrome, as the design direction is to keep things as simple as possible for end users.

Comment: Actually, I've just found out that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> shortcut is documented at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: @hanxue The original problem with `Alt + [` that was switching tabs instead of typing `[` has been fixed since this question was posted. It was an issue with french keyboard layout and Chrome. Here's the bug report : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stumbled upon an [undocumented shortcut](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=25799&answer=157179&rd=2) in Google Chrome. The shortcut that you mention is actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, which scrolls through each of the developer tabs in sequence from right to left.

A quick way around it is to use the [Keyconfig extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyconfig/okneonigbfnolfkmfgjmaeniipdjkgkl) to re-map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to `no action`.

Comment: your link to the keyconfig extension is a 404